# Architecture question: client REST API's caching solution

Tags: asp.net, rest, client, data-access-layer, distributed-caching

I'm implementing a high traffic client web application that uses a lot of REST API's for its data access layer from the cloud database. I said client because it implements REST and not provides it.

REST APIs are implemented server side as well as client side and I need to figure out a good solution for caching. The application is running on a web farm so it I'm leaning toward a distributed caching like memcached. This caching solution will need to be like a proxy layer between my application and REST APIs and support both client side as well as server side.

For example if I make a call to update a record I would update through REST and I'd like to keep updated record in the cache so next calls to that record won't need extra call to the outside REST services.

I want to minimize REST calls as much as possible and would need to keep the data accurate as much as I can, but it doesn't need to be 100% accurate.

What is the best solution for this caching proxy? Is it a standalone application that runs on one of the servers with local cache, or built into current solution using distributed caching? what are you ideas, suggestion or concerns

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hit the nail on the head.  You need a caching layer that acts as a proxy to your data.

I suggest that you create a layer that abstracts the concept of the cloud a way a bit.  Your client shouldn't care where the data comes from.  I would create a repository layer that communicates with the cloud and all other data.  Then you can put a service layer on top of that that your client would actually call into.  Inside this service layer is where you would implement things like your caching layer.

I used to always suggest using MemCached or [MemCached Win32](http://jehiah.cz/projects/memcached-win32/) depending on your environment.  MemCached win32 works really well if you are in a windows world!  Look to the [Enyim](http://www.codeplex.com/EnyimMemcached) client for MemCached win32...it is the least problematic of all the other ports.

If you are open to it though and you are in a .net world then you might try [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx).  MS finally got the clue that there was a hole in their caching framework in that they needed to support the farm concept.  Velocity last time I checked is not out of beta yet...but still worth a look.

I generally suggest using the repository and service layer concepts from day one...even though you don't need it.  The flexibility it provides for your application is worth having as you never know which direction your application will need to be pulled in.  Needing to scale is usually the best reason to need this flexibility.  But usually when you need to scale you need to scale now and refactoring in a repository layer and services layer while not impossible is usually semi-complex to do down the road.

Comment: Thanks for your input, how would that layer be consumed client-size in the browser with javascript?

Comment: Generally you would expose web services to your application from your application.  The web services would be the presentation layer for your services layer.  jquery->web services(returns json)->services layer->caching->repository->etc...

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This is definitely a lot of work since I have to abstract all the REST APIs with my layer... but i don't see any other way

Comment: Once you get all the abstractions in place you will find that your application is considerably more flexible.  Which means that when the next big thing is requested it will be much easier to get it plugged in.